# Python: Change variable suffix with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, variable-names

I know this was asked a lot but I can not work with/understand the answers so far.

I want to change the suffix of variables in a for loop.

I tried all answers the stackoverflow search provides. But it is difficult to understand specific codes the questioner often presents.

So for clarification I use an easy example. This is not meant as application-oriented. I just want to understand how I can change the suffix.

```py
var_1 = 10
var_2 = 100
var_3 = 1000

for i in range(1,4):
    test_i = var_i + 1
    print(test_i)
```

**Expected result**:
creating and printing variables:

```
test_1 = 11 
test_2 = 101 
test_3 = 1001
```

**Expected Output**

```py
11
101
1001
```

Error: `var_i` is read as a variable name without the changes for `i`.

Comment: If there were 100 values, do you create 100 variables? Use data structures to store values (ex: list).

Comment: There is a way to do this, but it's almost certainly not what you want. Have you heard of a `list`?

Comment: Use a dictionary or a list. As mentioned, this is basically always a Bad Idea™

Comment: This puts into this conundrum. https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201207/bad_answers_on_stack_overflow.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a convoluted naming convention, try to conceive of your problem using a data structure like dictionaries, for example.

```
var={}
var[1] = 10
var[2] = 100
var[3] = 1000

test={}
for i in range(1,4):
    test[i] = var[i] +1

print(test)
```

If somehow you are given `var_1` etc as input, maybe use `.split("_")` to retrieve the index number and use that as the dictionary keys (they can be strings or values).

---

*Small explanation about using indexing variable names.* If you are starting out learning to program, there are many reasons not to use the `eval`, `exec`, or `getattr` methods. Most simply, it is inefficient, **not scalable**, and is extremely hard to use anywhere else in the script.

I am not one to insist on "best practices" if there is an easier way to do something, but this is something you will want to learn to avoid. We write programs to avoid having to type things like this.

If you are given that `var_2` text as a starting point, then I would use string parsing tools to `split` and convert the string to values and variable names.

By using a dictionary, you can have 1000 non-consecutive variables and simply loop through them or assign new associations. If you are doing an experiment, for example, and call your values `tree_1`, `tree_10` etc, then you will always be stuck typing out the full variable names in your code rather than simply looping through all the entries in a container called `tree`.

This is a little related to using a bunch of `if:else` statements to assign values:

```
# inefficient way -- avoid
if name == 'var_1' then:
    test_1=11
elif name == 'var_2' then:
    test_2=101
```

It is so much easier just to say:

```
test[i]= var[i]+1
```

and that one line will work for any number of values.

Comment: With this it just adds 10,100 and 100 to the list. It does not compute 10+1,100+1 and 1000+1.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that but the point was just to show a possible alternative to all the `eval` answers.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now with the correct code this seems the most readable, easiest and low-risk solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against using `eval` in 99.99% of all cases. What you could do is use the built-in `getattr` function:

```
import sys
var_1 = 10
var_2 = 100
var_3 = 1000

for i in range(1,4):
    test_i = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], f"var_{i}") + 1
    print(test_i)
```

Comment: This looks painful but it works.<br> Just to make sure ```getattr(sys.modules[__name__], f"var_{i}")``` is my variable var_i right?

Comment: That's correct. `sys.modules[__name__]` is the current module, whereas  `f"var_{i}" is var 1 to 3. And [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) is simply there to access the variables

Comment: the `test_i` line gives me a syntax error in python 2 and 3, and doesn't assign the variables `test_1`, `test_2` etc, just re-uses `test_i`

Comment: @beroe the f-string syntax is python 3.6+. 2.7 is almost out the door (thankfully) and [almost all major libraries](https://python3statement.org/) do not support it anymore and I'd advise you to ditch it as well. I'd put 3.5 on the same boat as well given [there's almost no movement there](https://github.com/python/cpython/commits/3.5) and it's original release was 5 years ago. I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. The f-strings do look fun, but I forgot they were not in 3.5.

Comment: I also solved the problem. Among the answers to similar questions, it is the easiest to follow and can be used in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 4):
   print(eval('var_' + str(i)))
```

Step by step:

1) Make your variables strings:

`stringified_number = str(i)`

2) evaluate your expression during runtime:

`evaluated_variable = eval('var_' + stringified_number)`

Comment: This produces the error: "NameError: name 'var_10' is not defined"

Comment: @MartinFlower just removed the part with the list

Comment: `var_1 = 10
var_2 = 100
var_3 = 1000
for i in range(1, 4):
    test_i = eval('var_' + str(i)) + 1
    print(test_i)` Right. This works fine, Is understandable and good readable.